# Unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

The query looks very much correct to me. On looking up, it seems there is a precedence issue in the query.

The issue is at this line - `group_membership_settings.group_id = groups.id`

Unknown column `groups.id` in 'on clause'

```
 SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `groups`.`name` AS `profile_name`, ( 
        SELECT IF(
          group_membership_settings.max_limit, 
          group_membership_settings.max_limit > ( 
            SELECT COUNT(connection_memberships.id) FROM connection_memberships
            WHERE connection_memberships.type = 'Connection::MenteeMembership' 
            AND connection_memberships.group_id = groups.id
          ), 1) 
        FROM programs 
          INNER JOIN roles ON roles.program_id = programs.id AND roles.name = 'student'
          LEFT JOIN group_membership_settings ON group_membership_settings.group_id = groups.id AND group_membership_settings.role_id = roles.id
        WHERE programs.id = groups.program_id
    ) AS `available_to_join` FROM `groups`
```

Answer (score 0):

The table (alias) `groups` is not in scope *inside* its own definition.

You can only refer to columns from tables in the local query, ie `programs`, `roles` or `group_membership_settings`.

I can't tell what your intention is, but you might have to also join to `groups` in the inner query.